# Write to stdout in another isolate cause exception

Tags: flutter, dart, stdout, dart-isolates

Environment

- Windows 10
- Flutter 3.0.5
- Dart 2.17.6

Here is the code

```
void main() async {
  var errorReceivePort = ReceivePort();
  errorReceivePort.listen((message) {
    writeLogOnMainIoslate('Background service error : ${message.toString()}');
  });
  await writeLogOnMainIoslate(
      'prepare to write something to stdout in main isolate');
  stdout.write('write something in main isolate');
  await writeLogOnMainIoslate('${stdout.hasTerminal}\r\n');
  await Isolate.spawn(f, Object(), onError: errorReceivePort.sendPort);
}

void f(Object o) async {
  await writeLogOnOtherIsolate(
      'prepare to write something to stdout in other isolate');
  try {
    stdout.write('some message in other isolate');
  } catch (error) {
    await writeLogOnOtherIsolate(error.toString());
  }
  await writeLogOnOtherIsolate('end of other isolate');
}
```

then I got an error from errorReceivePort

```
Background service error : [FileSystemException: writeFrom failed, path = '' (OS Error: 控制代碼無效。
, errno = 6), #0      _RandomAccessFile.writeFromSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:873)
#1      _StdConsumer.addStream.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/stdio.dart)
#2      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618)
#3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341)
#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271)
#5      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774)
#6      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:648)
#7      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596)
#8      _StreamSinkImpl.add (dart:io/io_sink.dart:136)
#9      _IOSinkImpl.write (dart:io/io_sink.dart:269)
#10     _StdSink.write (dart:io/stdio.dart:315)
#11     f (package:a/main.dart:40)
```

Even if when running a Flutter app, stdout has no terminal, I expect same behavior in any isolate

My questions are

1. Why the try-catch does not work for this condition?
2. Use stdout in main isolate works(at least no error), but not works for another isolate

Comment: it would help if you provided the complete source code as the stack trace line numbers don't line up with your sample code. Your code also looks problematic as it appears recursively call writeLogOnOtherIsolate spawning a new isolate each time.